# Less than or equal to;

Tags: mysql, sql

When running my code I have no idea why it is not running.

```
USE premierproducts;

SELECT partnum AND description
FROM parts
WHERE class <> SG;
```

I've also tried `SG` and != for class !=SG; 
And I always get the error 1054 unknown column `SG` in where clause.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT partnum, description FROM parts WHERE class <> 'SG';
```

Select columns separated by commas and SG is probably a string so need to be wrapped in single quotes.

Comment: When ran it still gives me the error in the where clause, But thank you for finding my AND mistake!

Comment: Error code: 1054: Unknown column `SG` in `where clause`

Comment: @jake - In my answer, you can see it's wrapped in single quotes. Assuming that it is a string that need to be compared with class column. Try it that way.

Comment: Oh I am dumb, I was using tick marks instead of the quote. completely my mistake.  How would I do it for numbers then? For example
SELECT partnum, description, onhand
FROM parts
WHERE parts >= (10);?

Comment: @jake - There is no need to put anything for numbers. They can be writtern directly like `where col = 123`. For strings you need to write like `where col = 'abc'`

Comment: Ah ok, I see the technical errors I have been doing. That what always kills me, thank you.  Ill accept the answer when it allows me to.

Comment: @jake - Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

`<>` or `!=` not equal to

`<=` less than or equal to

`>=` greater than equal to

`>` greater than

`<` less than

`=` equal

Your issue is that you're comparing it to `SG` (treating it as column), if it's a string, you should do `'SG'`

Answer (score 1):

you should give `'SG'` enclosed by single quotes . if you are not giving it in single quotes, then it will consider SG as column name

> note:
>
> 1) Column name and table name  should be enclosed by back ticks
>
> 2) string enclosed by single quotes
>
> 3) No need to  put quotes for number

```
SELECT `partnum`, `description` FROM `parts` WHERE `class` != 'SG';
```